# Applying CSS on JQUERY Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm new in JQuery mobile. I'm finding it very difficult to apply some `CSS` to my JQUERY mobile script.

I need to do the following:

- List item
- change page color
- change navbar buttons color
- change navbar buttons height to 48px
- Align text in the middle of navbar buttons
- Re-size navbar Icons size

Then regarding the listview:

- change list height to 48px
- change list colors
- change list font size to 16px

Please help to solve this problem!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/spinbox/latest/jqm-spinbox.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
}
.navTxtSize {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: middle;
}
.liListItem {
    height: 48px;
}
#hea .ui-btn {
    height: 48px;
}
</style>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div>
      <h2>CSS</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top" id="hea" class="ui-body-c">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#inputDialog" data-icon="plus">
          <div class="navTxtSize">Add Item</div>
          </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="checkList()" data-icon="delete">
          <div  class="navTxtSize">Delete ALL</div>
          </a></li>
        <li><a onclick="loadItemsForList1()" data-icon="shop" >
          <div  class = "navTxtSize">Shop</div>
          </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form class="ui-filterable">
      <input id="myFilter" placeholder="Enter Item Name" data-type="search">
    </form>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true" id = "itemsList" data-split-icon="delete">
      <li class=liListItem"><a class="listItem">Example1</a><a class="removal"></a></li>
      <li class=liListItem"><a class="listItem">Example2</a><a class="removal"></a></li>
      <li class=liListItem"><a class="listItem">Example3</a><a class="removal"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you recreate it in JSFiddle or internally?

Comment: here it is :   https://jsfiddle.net/11vjkrou/1/

Comment: What were you trying to change? Which colors? Which elements? I see that the navlist items are already 48px with 16px font size, am I mistaken?

Comment: But these are not working. Also i need to add further css as I listed in my question.

Comment: But these are not working. Also i need to add further css as I listed in my question. Yes. I managed to change navbar size and font size. I need to re-size icon and move a bit downwards all text in navbar buttons. Regarding the list <li> I wish to change the height. How this can be done?

Comment: @Stephen: please let me know if mark the styles as `!important` solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the relevant selectors for your need:

Navbar:

```
.ui-navbar li .ui-btn {
  background-color: blanchedalmond !important;
}
```

Listview:

```
.ui-listview li > .ui-btn {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  height: 48px;
}
```

Icons:

```
.ui-btn::after {
    background-size: 32px !important;
    width: 32px !important;
    height: 32px !important;
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    background-color: darksalmon;
}
```

But there is a little bit some more work, to adjust the icon margins and border radius.

You may use this as starting point to play with, because you haven't exactly specified how big your icons shall be.

Also the button on the right side of the listview need a bit custom styling due to the increased icon size:

```
.ui-listview>li.ui-li-has-alt>.ui-btn+.ui-btn {
  width: 68px;
}

.ui-btn-icon-notext:after, .ui-btn-icon-left:after, .ui-btn-icon-right:after {
  margin-left: -16px;
}
```

I removed all your CSS classes to show a clean result with just only the JQM styles overridden here: https://jsfiddle.net/a3ckna8w/4/

Be aware that jQuery Mobile may override your CSS styles, so you should mark yours as `!important`. For an explanation why this happens see here: [Html5 - Css styles are overriden by jquery mobile style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511080/html5-css-styles-are-overriden-by-jquery-mobile-style).